# What's are some natural expressions to say when you pick up the order?

Tags: expressions, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Suppose I ordered some food online. What are some natural (and preferably concise) expressions to say when I arrive at the store?

Here are some that I can think of (they may not be natural or grammatical):

> Can I get the order for Alex?
>
> Is the order for Alex ready?
>
> I placed an order online in the name of Alex.

Answer (score 0):

Any of those work.  I might use:

> - I placed a pickup order. The name is Alex.
> - I placed a pickup order. My name is Alex.
> - I'm here to get my order. It is under the name Alex.
> - My name is Alex. I ordered XYX, is it ready?
> - I have an order of XYZ coming. My name is Alex.

Some places do not primarily identify orders by name, others do. Some use phone number, or order number. Using whatever the establishment is used to will make things easier for everyone. The form "the order for Alex" suggests to me that someone other than Alex is picking up the order on Alex's behalf. This might be slightly confusing.

Comment: I agree that it may be confusing. In fact, I assumed the person picking up the order was **not** Alex, but someone else picking up the order **for** Alex. (If my assumption was wrong, I like your suggestions.)

Comment: @J.R. In my question Alex is supposed to be the one who is picking up the order. I didn't know that "the order for Alex" suggests what David Siegel wrote.

Comment: In the end, it might not make any difference. My name can be hard to pronounce, so I often use a nickname when I place an order. If I'm picking up a pizza, it only matters if the name I give them at the counter matches the name that was given when the order was placed. If I'm picking up a prescription, however, they are likely to ask me for an ID, so it's imperative that the name I give them matches my ID and the name on the order.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with the comment left by Lorel. Your suggestions sound fine, although I might be inclined to shorted the third one:

> I placed an order online **using the name** Alex.
>   I placed an order online **for** Alex.
>   I placed an order online **with the name** Alex.

---

That said, I think I would most likely use the phrasal verb you put in your title: *pick up*.

In other words, I might say:

> I'm here to pick up an order for Alex.